# How to properly show multiple videos in the same avPlayerLayer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

**What I'm trying to achieve?**

I'm showing users a subview with integrated page control. I want to show three different videos on the same subview.

**How I implemented avPlayer?**

*First step:*

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    avPlayerLayer.frame = (WelcomeView?.video.layer.bounds)!
}
```

*First video aligned perfectly in the middle of my view with this snippet of code:*

```
WelcomeView?.frame.size.width = deviceScreen.frame.size.width
WelcomeView?.frame.size.height = deviceScreen.frame.size.height
WelcomeView?.video.layer.cornerRadius = 15
WelcomeView?.video.clipsToBounds = true
WelcomeView?.gradient.layer.cornerRadius = 25
WelcomeView?.gradient.clipsToBounds = true
WelcomeView?.label.addShadow()
let theURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"welcome1", withExtension: "MP4")
avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: theURL!)
avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect
avPlayer.volume = 0
avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = .none
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
selector: #selector(playerItemDidReachEnd(notification:)),
name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
object: avPlayer.currentItem)
WelcomeView?.video.frame = (WelcomeView?.video.layer.bounds)!
WelcomeView?.video.layer.insertSublayer(self.avPlayerLayer, at: 0)
WelcomeView?.tapNext.addTarget(self, action: #selector(GalleryViewController.nextOutboarding(sender:)))
self.view.addSubview(WelcomeView!)
avPlayer.play()
```

*Second step (when user clicks on the button next and when I'm trying to show different video on the same subview):*

```
    @objc func nextOutboarding(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    WelcomeView?.pageControl.currentPage += 1
    
    if WelcomeView?.pageControl.currentPage == 1 {
        avPlayer.pause()
        avPlayerLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        let theURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"welcome2", withExtension: "MP4")
        avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: theURL!)
        avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
        avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect
        avPlayer.volume = 0
        avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = .none
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
        selector: #selector(playerItemDidReachEnd(notification:)),
        name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
        object: avPlayer.currentItem)
        WelcomeView?.video.frame = (WelcomeView?.video.layer.bounds)!
        WelcomeView?.video.layer.insertSublayer(self.avPlayerLayer, at: 0)
        self.view.addSubview(WelcomeView!)
        avPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

**My problem:**

When I'm trying to show second video on the same avPlayerLayer - my video has different alignment (basically not in the middle anymore).

Any tips? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, create new `AvPlayerItem`.

```
var playerItem:AVPlayerItem?
```

Then use `replaceCurrentItem` function.

```
playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: theURL!)
avPlayer.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
```

That's it. Now you can reuse existing avPlayer.

Comment: Brilliant solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding new subview with `AVPlayerLayer` every time user clicks next, you should reuse the `AVPlayerLayer` that you've already added to play the next video. In your code, you're trying to add the `WelcomeView` again as the subview but it's already is a subview and the previous layer has all the properties that you've set to it and you don't need to repeat that.

```
@objc func nextOutboarding(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    WelcomeView?.pageControl.currentPage += 1

    if WelcomeView?.pageControl.currentPage == 1 {
        avPlayer.pause()
        let theURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"welcome2", withExtension: "MP4")
        avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: theURL!)
        avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
        avPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for good code practise! But my problem not solved.. alignment is still messed up. EDIT: actually the problem with your suggestion is that new video not showing up.

Comment: Make sure you're not removing the avplayerlayer or the subview from it's super class.